# How to make NMAP command steady and the fastest possible?

Tags: wifi, scanning, nmap

I want to make an IP scan using NMAP, but the operating time varies for some reason. The command can be executed in 2 seconds, an if I launch it again just after, it can take 30 seconds.

This is the command I use :

> nmap -n -sn -T5 --max-rtt-timeout 1s

-n : no DNS resolution

-sn : disable port scan

-T5 fast mode

--max-rtt-timeout round trip timeout for the probes 1s

I don't know if my optimisation is good ? And how to make it better ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In my case, adding min-parallelism in original command improved scan time from 26.54 second to 3.26 second:

```
nmap -n -sn -T5 --max-rtt-timeout 1s --min-parallelism 100 172.27.192.0-255
```

Answer (score 1):

Some debug output (`-d --packet-trace` would be a good start) would be very helpful to diagnose this problem. My first thought was that you were telling Nmap to use timeouts that were too short, leading to retransmissions when they don't need to happen. But that probably wouldn't lead to 30-second run times; the response would be seen and accepted as soon as it came in, even if the probe was retransmitted first.

More helpful information would be the version and platform of Nmap (`nmap --version`), whether your command is run with root or administrator privileges, and what kind of network you are scanning on. The question is tagged [wifi](/questions/tagged/wifi), but you don't say whether the target is on the same link as you, or several network hops away.

Most importantly for you, you should learn [what `-T5` really means](https://nmap.org/book/man-performance.html#idm214689427808) so that you can make rational decisions when tweaking performance variables. Not only is `-T5` not properly "fast mode," but you have set the round-trip timeout to be 3 times longer than `-T5` defaults to, which is probably a good signal that the rest of the variables are not where they need to be. Try `-T4` or even the default `-T3` and see if the timing stabilizes. I would not be surprised if it turns out to be nearly as fast as your best `-T5` times.

Answer (score 0):

For port scanning, these settings may be a little strict, but helps with speed:

`--min-hostgroup 256 --max-rtt-timeout 100ms --max-retries 1`

`--min-hostgroup` = Splits the IPs up in groups for parrallel scanning.  In this case, I'm scanning the entire subnet.

`--max-retries 1` = Port scan re-send if fail.

For further help, please refer to the [nmap timing and performance documentation.](https://nmap.org/book/man-performance.html)